# Primeng p-selectbutton onOptionClick event

Tags: angular, button, events, primeng

I try to make an unselect function for primeng p-selectbutton. I have a yes/no p-selectbutton when I click on an already selected value, I want to clear the variable.

So I select 'true', the button turn to 'true', I select 'false', it turn to false, and if I click again on false, it turn to null.

Html:

```
<p-selectButton
   [options]="optionsYesNo"
   id="myvariable"
   name="myvariable"
   [(ngModel)]="myvariable"
   (onOptionClick)="test('myvariable', $event)"></p-selectButton>
```

Ts:

```
test(variable, event){
  if (this[variable] === event.option.value) {
    this[variable] = null;
  } else {
    this[variable] = event.option.value;
  }
  // Update the p-selectButton in the DOM
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

This code seems to work, when 'true' is selected and I click again, the DOM is updated, my p-selectbutton appears deselected but the value of myvariable remains at 'true' (I tested it with another independent button launching `console.log(this.myvariable)`).

Comment: Ok, I changed to
setTimeout(() =>{this[variable] = null});
It worked but I don't understand why and how to properly use setTimeout